# Updating designated column with Date updated and Username

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a larger spreadsheet that is updated by multiple users across a number of parameters. In order to help understand what information is up to date and by whom. For confidentiality reasons, I cannot share the exact sheet, but can make an exemplary one to help.

So far I have gotten the updated date to show for any column (3-17); but I haven't been able to get the designated column to work properly. I have also been able to get a singular user name to show, but not associated with the specific row in question.

Structure - 
- columns designate categories for updated data
- rows designate the program of the updated data
- in the same row, we want to show who and when updated the information

Current code:

Update:: (Error: TypeError: Cannot find function setValue in object R##)

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "Budget" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 ) { //checks the column
     var updateCell = 'R'+ r.getRowIndex();
       var time = new Date();
       time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-8", "MM/dd - HH:mm");
       updateCell.setValue(time);
   };
 };
}
```

Username:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    e.source.getActiveSheet()
    // Set the cell you want to update with the user.
    .getRange('B1')
    // Update the user (only email is available, and only if security settings allow).
    .setValue(e.user.getEmail() );
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how to interpret your code snippets - do you have two `onEdit` functions in your script?

Comment: There are two snippets actually. I didn't see a clear way to merge them until I independently got each section to work correctly

Comment: You can have only one onEdit() function per script, this would explain why it is not working properly for you. Combine both functions in one - or give them different names and call them both from an `onEdit()` function.

Comment: They are named and saved separately. Do you know why each may not be working independently?

Comment: Because if you define multiple functions with the same name, the last one overwrites the previous ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be some issues with the code you shared.

1. The second if-statement does not have the correct syntax
2. setValue expects a range-object but is given a string ('R' + r.getRowIndex())
3. In using two onEdits (sharing the same trigger) only one will work when actual edits are done.

This script should output the time in column R and the email of the editor in column S. See if this helps ?

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (s.getName() == "Budget" && [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17].indexOf(e.range
        .columnStart) > -1) {
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-8", "MM/dd - HH:mm");
    s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 18, 1, 2).setValues([
        [time, e.user.email]
    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: I get the error Syntax error: Missing ; before statement. line: 1 file: Date Trial 2. Tried replacing { with ; and error message persists

Comment: Got this to work. It was a permissions issue on my end actually. The error code is misleading